# how to get data within a specific date range from Excel

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I am trying to get a data from Excel using C#. My Excel data contains several records but I need the data which is between two dates.

I tried with the following code :

```
OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand("select field1,field2,joiningdate from [Sheet1$] where joiningdate >=to_date('"+startDate+"','MM/DD/YYYY') and joiningdate <=to_date('"+endDate+"','MM/DD/YYYY')", con);
```

I can get the values of startDate and endDate through DateTimePicker control..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select field1,field2,joiningdate from [Sheet1$] 
where joiningdate between CDate(startDate) and CDate(endDate)
```

This is assuming that your joiningdate column is formatted as Date type.